# How make history of excution job with java Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz

i am using java Quartz to run a job to be run every day, and i am using option use jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX to try to create history of these run job, i want start time and end with end status.

And another question, are there any light monitoring for my job ?

Actualy in my database i have only 1 rows in qrtz_cron_triggers and qrtz_job_details

Answer (score 0):

yYou can use the JobExecutionListeners which are callbacks and can get the start and end time from the context.
Use these callbacks carefully as they might impact the Job execution if you do  an expensive operations.
The more details can be found here[enter link description here][1]

Quartz Listeners [1]: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-07.html